# Loading saved SURF keypoints

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, surf

I am detecting SURF features in an image and then writing them to a `yml` file. I then want to load the features from the `yml` file again to try and detect an object but at the moment I'm having trouble loading the keypoints to draw them on an image.

I'm writing the keypoints like so:

```
cv::FileStorage fs("keypointsVW.yml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
write(fs, "keypoints_1", keypoints_1);
fs.release();
```

I am trying to read them like so:

```
cv::FileStorage fs2("keypointsVW.yml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
read(fs2, "keypoints_1", keypoints_1);
fs2.release();
```

But this is producing a host of errors.

Detection and draw code:

```
    cv::Mat img_1 = cv::imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    int minHessian = 400;
    cv::SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints_1;
    detector.detect(img_1, keypoints_1);
    cv::Mat img_keypoints_1;
    //......write code
    //.......read code
    drawKeypoints(img_1, keypoints_1, img_keypoints_1);
    imshow("keypoints_1", img_keypoints_1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, I'll post it here in case anyone else has the same problem.

```
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> testPoints;
cv::FileStorage fs2("keypointsVW.yml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
cv::FileNode kptFileNode = fs2["keypointsVW"];
read(kptFileNode, testPoints);
fs2.release();
```