# Error with cv::read

Tags: c++, opencv

Hello I am developing an application on Qt where I implement SURF algorithm on GPU.

When I put this:

```
FileStorage file1("requete.txt", cv::FileStorage::READ);
file1[path.toStdString()] >> descriptor1;
```

where "requete.txt" contains descriptors, I have the following error "between" the two lines of code:

> penCV Error: Unspecified error (The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)) in cvRead, file /home/dev/Téléchargements/opencv-new/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 4991
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /home/dev/Téléchargements/opencv-new/opencv-.4.10/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:4991: error: (-2) The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?) in function cvRead

What should I do to get rid of the error?

Comment: What's this `file1[path.toStdString()]`? Can you try instead `file >> descriptor`;`?

Comment: @Antonio : 
 `/home/dev/Desktop/PierreDeHand/HelloWordGroupeCG/form.cpp:185: error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'cv::FileStorage' and 'cv::Mat')
     file1 >> descriptor1;`

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27841178/2436175) help? In case, we can mark this question duplicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading saved SURF keypoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841067/loading-saved-surf-keypoints)

Comment: @Antonio It seems that I need some help in addition...